# How to cast generic type after isAssignableFrom check in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

See the example:

```
class MyTypeAdapter<T : Throwable>
    (private val gson: Gson, private val skipPast: TypeAdapterFactory) : TypeAdapter<T>() {
   // :Throwable is needed to access the stackTrace field
}

private class ThrowableTypeAdapterFactory : TypeAdapterFactory {
    override fun <T> create(gson: Gson, typeToken: TypeToken<T>): TypeAdapter<T>? {
        if (Throwable::class.java.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.rawType)) {
            return MyTypeAdapter<T>(gson, this) // compile error: Type argument is not within its bound
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

So in Java we have raw use parameterized class but Kotlin doesn't allow it anymore.
I tried to find something from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html
but couldn't get a clue. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to cheat thanks to type erasure:

```
return MyTypeAdapter<Throwable>(gson, this) as MyTypeAdapter<T>
```

It looks wrong, but the class can't actually do anything different depending on `T`.

Or if Kotlin won't accept this cast directly (can't check at the moment) something like

```
return (MyTypeAdapter<Throwable>(gson, this) as MyTypeAdapter<*>) as MyTypeAdapter<T>
```

or even

```
return (MyTypeAdapter<Throwable>(gson, this) as Any) as MyTypeAdapter<T>
```

should work.

Comment: I have tried the first one doesn’t compile. The bound error is from the constructor parameter T. The second and third can compile and it doesn’t solve the problem. Because I expect to pass the class T into my adapter instead of Throwable.

Comment: `class MyTypeAdapter<T : Throwable>(private val gson: Gson, private val skipPast: TypeAdapterFactory)` doesn't actually pass any class into the constructor and will behave exactly the same at runtime for any `T`. That's the point.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood how Java generic works. The type information is removed after compilation. Thanks for your answer! Accepted it